# How to retrive values from hashmap in which key is item of combobox in vaadin

Tags: java, combobox, hashmap, vaadin

I want to store and retrieve a key value associated with the comboBox. I have used only getSelectedIndex() and getSelectedItem(). This will not help my purpose as I have to get a unique key value assocaiated with the item.

Example Scenario :

India - 10, China - 15, Russia - 18. Here if 'India' is the comboBox item then '10' is its key. Likewise, 15 for china and 18 for Russia.

When India is selected I need to get the value as 10, if china 15, if Russia 18.

How can I achieve this in vaadin. could you guys guide me to do this.

Comment: Let's say your data is encapsulated in class `CountryValue`. You would make your combo box with the class and make `CountryValue.toString()` return the country name. You can get the value with `CountryValue.getValue()`

Comment: how to achieve this in vaadin ? could you please share the code snippet if possible ?

Comment: What does the number represent?

Comment: I have just taken as key

Comment: What does the number *mean*?

Comment: number represents country id

Answer (score 2):

As suggested create a class Country:

```
public class Country {

     private Integer key;
     private String name;

     // getters and setters
}
```

And then call `setItems()` with the collection of Country.

`getSelectedItem()` will then return the selected Country and you can get the Key.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Country {
    private String name;
    private int id;

    public Country() {
    }

    public Country(String name, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Will do it for you.